# ERROR {"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred .."}

Tags: c#, asp.net

I got an Error at line myconn.Open(); How to solve it.

```
 {"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error:}


SqlConnection myconn = new SqlConnection();
        String connection = "Data Source=SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\Winer\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2008\\WebSites1\\App_Data\\Database.mdf";
        myconn.ConnectionString = connection;
        myconn.Open();
```

Can any one say about it ?

Comment: Error 1 Unrecognized escape sequence at line .\SQLEXPRESS

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/ is a good source for your connection strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It just means that the server `SQLEXPRESS` was not found. I think you have a typo error. Try this if it works: (`Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;`)

```
String connection = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\Winer\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2008\\WebSites1\\App_Data\\Database.mdf";
```

**UPDATE 1:**

`.` means or equivalent to `localhost`

`Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;` is the same as `Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;`

or try

`Data Source=YOURCOMPUTERNAME\SQLEXPRESS;`

**UPDATE 2**

Why not use this Connection String format?

```
Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;Integrated Security=SSPI;
```

OR

```
Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

WHERE

**myServerAddress** is your server address
**myDataBase** is the name of your database
**myUsername** is the username as well as
**myPassword** your password.

**[More ConnectionString format on this link.](http://connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005)**

Comment: Error Occurs at line .\SQLEXPRESS :  
Error 1 Unrecognized escape sequence at line .\SQLEXPRESS

Comment: Needs a double backslash, or an @ before the ", or the compiler will be looking for the escape character \S.  If you use the @, you can remove the double backslashes in the file path.

Comment: try the word localhost or the name of your computer.

Comment: @TheEvilPenguin yep that's why I changed it to `Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS`

Comment: @johntotetwoo I have done Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS .but at myconn.open() I got {"Login failed for user ''. The user is not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection."}

Comment: meaning you now have found the databse server but you haven't supply the login credentials. I Updated my answer.

Comment: How to give  login credentials ?

Comment: check out this link: http://support.gearhost.com/KB/a453/adding-users-to-mssql-using-sql-server-management-studio.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your connection string is valid. I tend to recommend this to students:

1. In the 'Server Explorer' panel, use the wizard to create a connection to the
   database.
2. On the new connection, in the 'Data Connections' section, right-click on the connection to display the context menu.
3. Select 'Properties'. Copy and paste the 'Connection String' value in
   place of your existing string.

There are better ways to do this, but this is relatively simple, I think. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlConnection myconn = new SqlConnection();         
String connection = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Winer\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\WebSites1\App_Data\Database.mdf";         
myconn.ConnectionString = connection;         
myconn.Open();
```